# JavaFX, Validate text fields on the fly with a Listener and with immediate error report

Tags: java, validation, javafx

I'm doing a Calendar/Schedule of Appointments for my exam project.
It has functions like add, remove, edit, order by date and search by name and date functions. I already implemented them.
The appointments have: name, date, hour, place and duration properties, and are visualized in a TableView.
I only have to implement the field validations.

The properties are inserted through a DialogPane, that is a GridPane of this form:

```
                              Error Label (eg Empty Field)
```

Suggestion label (eg Insert name):      TextField where the user inserts the input

Only the place field can be empty. **And if during a certain moment there is already an appointment, the user cannot add a new one.**
I don't want to use annoying Alerts, but for every error the red Error Label has to change. **If all the error labels become empty, the OK button is enabled, and the user can add the new appointment.**

But I obtained only a lot of mess code. I will post the add and the validate method:

```
@FXML
public void mostraDialogoInserisciAppuntamento(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.initOwner(borderPanePrincipale.getScene().getWindow());
    dialog.setTitle("Aggiungi un Nuovo Appuntamento");
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("dialogoInserisciModifica.fxml"));
    try {
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Non riesco a caricare il dialogo per l'inserimento");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
    dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK).setDisable(true);
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);

    controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
    controller.getCampoData().setValue(LocalDate.now());
    controller.getErroreNome().setText("Campo nome vuoto!");
    controller.getCampoOrario().setText(LocalTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")));
    controller.getErroreDurata().setText("Campo durata vuoto!");
    controller.getErroreDurata().setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("red"));


    verificaCorrettezzaDati(controller, dialog);

    Optional<ButtonType> click = dialog.showAndWait();
    if (click.isPresent() && click.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
        Appuntamento nuovoAppuntamento = controller.raccogliCampi(null);
        vistaAppuntamenti.getSelectionModel().select(nuovoAppuntamento);
    }
}

private void verificaCorrettezzaDati(DialogController controller, Dialog<ButtonType> dialog) {

    // Verifica correttezza campo nome
    controller.getCampoNome().textProperty().addListener((observable, valoreVecchio, valoreNuovo) -> {
        if (valoreNuovo.trim().isEmpty()) {
            controller.getErroreNome().setText("Campo nome vuoto!");
        } else {
            controller.getErroreNome().setText("");
        }
    });

    // Verifica correttezza campo data
    controller.getCampoData().editorProperty().addListener((observable, valoreVecchio, valoreNuovo) -> {
        if (valoreNuovo.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            controller.getErroreData().setText("Campo data vuoto!");
        } else if (!valoreNuovo.toString().matches("([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})")) {
            controller.getErroreData().setText("Formato data non valido!");
        } else {
            controller.getErroreData().setText("");
        }
    });

    // Verifica correttezza campo ora
    controller.getCampoOrario().textProperty().addListener((observable, valoreVecchio, valoreNuovo) -> {
        if (valoreNuovo.trim().isEmpty()) {
            controller.getErroreOrario().setText("Campo ora vuoto!");
        } else if (!valoreNuovo.matches("([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})")) {
            controller.getErroreOrario().setText("Formato orario non valido!");
        } else {
            controller.getErroreOrario().setText("");
            for (Appuntamento appuntamento : Agenda.getIstanza().getAppuntamenti()) {
                if ((valoreNuovo.equals(appuntamento.getOrario())) && (controller.getCampoData().toString().equals(appuntamento.getData().toString()))) {
                    controller.getErroreOrario().setText("Hai già un appuntamento a quest'ora!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Verifica correttezza campo durata
    controller.getCampoDurata().textProperty().addListener((observable, valoreVecchio, valoreNuovo) -> {
        if (valoreNuovo.trim().isEmpty()) {
            controller.getErroreDurata().setText("Campo durata vuoto!");
        } else if(!valoreNuovo.trim().matches("[0-9]+")) {
            controller.getErroreDurata().setText("Esprimi la durata come un intero!");
        } else {
            controller.getErroreDurata().setText("");
            LocalTime oraIniziale = LocalTime.parse(controller.getCampoOrario().toString().trim());
            LocalTime oraFinale = oraIniziale.plusMinutes(Integer.parseInt(valoreNuovo));
            for (Appuntamento appuntamento : Agenda.getIstanza().getAppuntamenti()) {
                if ((oraIniziale.compareTo(appuntamento.getOrario()) >= 0) &&
                        (oraFinale.compareTo(appuntamento.getOrario().plusMinutes(appuntamento.getDurata())) <= 0) &&
                        (controller.getCampoData().toString().equals(appuntamento.getData().toString()))) {
                    controller.getErroreDurata().setText("Hai già un appuntamento dalle " + oraIniziale + " alle " + oraFinale + "!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    if ((controller.getErroreNome().getText().isEmpty()) && (controller.getErroreData().getText().isEmpty()) &&
            controller.getErroreOrario().getText().isEmpty() && (controller.getErroreDurata().getText().isEmpty())) {
        dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK).setDisable(false);
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm at a standstill...

Please help me find a way to organize the code (make a separate validation method for every field?) **or even better find a more simple validation** (store errors in an errors String and display with an Alert all them if the user press OK, and let create the new appointment it the errors string is empty?).

If you want to download as a .zip the entire project (I commented the validation part so you can run it and understand better its functionality): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-BuSpE73jX9ekJjQl9KZk83ZXM

Comment: You have three chunks of code that basically do the same thing (take a text field, an error label, and a collection of conditions to test, and set the error label to a specific message if the conditions are met). Try to write a method that does that and takes parameters for the things that vary (i.e. text field, label, conditions, which you can represent as `Predicate`s). Then you can greatly reduce the amount of code and make things more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I will first try to 1. Don't disable the OK button, 2. when the user press OK and some fields are not acceptable set at that point the error labels text; 3. If the validation is ok (all the error labels are empty), add the appointment. If I manage to do so then may try to use less code as you suggested.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand what the question is...